# SQL Server Application - Resetting database to original state

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, integration-testing

**Background**

I need to write some integration tests in C# (about 120 of them) for a C#/SQL Server application. Now, initially before any test, the database will already be there, the reason it will be there is because lot of scripts will be run to set it up (about 20 minutes running time). Now when I run my test, few tables will be updated (CRUD operations). For e.g. in 10-11 tables, few rows will be added and say in 15-16 tables, few rows will be updated and in 4-5 tables few rows will be deleted.

**Problem**

`After` every test is run, `the database` needs to be `reset` to it's original state. How can I achieve that?

**Bad Solution**

After every run of a test, `re-run` the database `creation scripts` (20 minutes of running time). Since there will be around 120 tests, this comes to 40 hours which is not an option. Secondly there is a process that has several connections open against this database so the database cannot be dropped/re-created.

**Good Solution?**

I would like to know if there is any other way of solving this problem? Another problem I have is that, for each of those tests, I don't even know what tables will be updated and I will have to manually go and check to see what tables were updated anyway if I were to delete, revert the database to it's original state manually by writing queries.

Comment: take a backup at the start, restore in between each test?

Comment: as @BugFinder said create backup with empty database and use script to restore before tests

Comment: @BugFinder and Sebastian - sorry, just modified the question. There is a process that has several connections open against this database so the database cannot be dropped/re-created. It will cause the process to terminate as well.

Comment: Then use a test copy of the database - if its running with something that means you have live connections...

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at the possibilities MSSQl gives you with taking a snapshot of your database. It is potentially a lot faster than reverting to a backup or recreating the database.

[Managing a test database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx)

> In a testing environment, it can be useful when repeatedly running a test protocol for the database to contain identical data at the start of each round of testing. Before running the first round, an application developer or tester can create a database snapshot on the test database. After each test run, the database can be quickly returned to its prior state by reverting the database snapshot.

Comment: It would be useful to provide some code to show how this can be achieved. Links can change over time.

Comment: Snapshots won't accept DB writes (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.) Makes for very limited tests.

Comment: @CleverPatrick You do not need to write to the snapshot. You use the snapshot to return the database to its prior state.